# Rust packaged in .deb

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo

I want to create a `.deb` package out of my Rust code. It consists of a library (crate) that is used by another library crate and a binary crate. So something like

```
- core_lib
- pam_lib (uses core_lib)
- cli_binary (uses core_lib)
```

#### Question 1

The issue is resolving dependencies, of course :-) I have tried two approaches:

###### Dynamic linking

When compiling the code, I can force where it should expect shared libraries to be found, as `cargo rustc -r -- -C link-args='-Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mylib'`. However, when I do this and `dpkg build` the package, `lintian` returns an error: `custom-library-search-path`.

###### Adding to `ldconfig`

I can also add a new config file to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and set a path to my `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mylib` dir, and execute `sudo ldconfig` in a `postinst` script to update the values. But **is this the right way to go?** I wouldn't like to follow any antipatterns.

#### Question 2

The other issue I'm having with these dependencies is that when I compile either of the 'final' binaries, it also compiles the `core_lib` in the `target/release` folder. So far, so good. But `libcore_lib.so` is not the same when I compile `pam_lib` or `cli_binary` (even byte size is somewhat different), and I cannot use them interchangeably. Not even when I compile `core_lib` independently and use that artifact; running either binary returns `unknown symbol` followed by a reference to a function from `core_lib`.

One possible solution would be to copy `libcore_lib.so` twice to different dirs (once for each binary from their own `target/release` dir), but since it is supposed to be a shared reference, that seems to be outright... stupid.

Any ideas, please?

Core library `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "core-lib"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["dylib"]

[dependencies]
...
```

and binaries `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "cli-binary"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
core-lib = { path = "../../Rust core/core-lib" }
...
```

Comment: Have you looked at `cargo-deb`?

Comment: Nope (I only have peeked at it just now), but I don't have issues with creating the `.deb` package. I'm having issues with `libcore_lib.so` being different for my lib and bin crates, and since I need to pack them both to a single `.deb` package, that's a bit disturbing :) Moreover, I'd need to squeeze both lib and bin to one crate to use `cargo-deb`, at least based on quick reading.
But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the dumb part was... me :-)

I was also browsing Rust forum and stumbled upon a [topic that resembled mine](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/sharing-a-crate-with-crate-type-dylib/66768) - and sure enough, when I changed the `core_lib` type from `dylib` to `lib`, it all started working. I just imposed a lot of headache upon me by using `dylib` for no real reason (switched to that long time ago for reasons I no longer remember... sigh).

Anyway, hope it helps someone else, too.